# How to remove last part of url in PHP

Tags: php

```
 $url = explode('/', $articleimage);
 $articleurl = array_pop($url);
```

I have used the above method to get the last part of a URL.Its working.But I want to remove the last part from the URL and display the remaining part.Please help me.Here I am mentioning the example URL.

```
http://www.brightknowledge.org/knowledge-bank/media/studying-media/student-media/image_rhcol_thin
```

Comment: so do a `var_dump($url)` and you'll see you've already got the rest.

Comment: you need to implode() the array again. if you want to string.

Comment: [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = explode('/', 'http://www.brightknowledge.org/knowledge-bank/media/studying-media/student-media/image_rhcol_thin');
array_pop($url);
echo implode('/', $url);
```

Comment: Would be perfect if we could give explode the 3rd param "limit", but unfortunately we cannot give a limit start starts from the right :/ _(Or anybody knows a "trick"?)_

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to use `explode`, `implode`, and `array_pop`.

Just use `dirname($path)`. It's a lot more efficient and cleaner code.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following string manipulation from PHP

```
$url_without_last_part = substr($articleimage, 0, strrpos($articleimage, "/"));
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Laravel**

```
dirname(url()->current())
```

In url()->current() -> you will get current URL.

In dirname -> You will get parent directory.

In Core PHP:

```
dirname($currentURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

after the `array_pop` you can do

```
$url2=implode("/",$url)
```

to get the url in a string

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$articleurl = array_pop($url);
```

Into this:

```
$articleurl = end($url);
```

$articleurl will then hold the last array key.

Missed the part where you want to remove the value, you can use the function key() to get the key and then remove the value using that key

```
$array_key = key($articleurl);
unset(url[$array_key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple solution add in the end of your code

```
$url = implode('/', $url);
echo $url;
```

Notice that array_pop use reference argument passing so array will be modifed implode() function does the opposite to explode function and connects array elements by first argument(glue) and returns the string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may be what you are looking for. Instead of exploding and imploding, you can use the parsing functions which are designed to handle exactly this kind of URL manipulation.

```
$url = parse_url( $url_string );

$result = 
    $url['scheme']
    . "://"
    . $url['host']
    . pathinfo($url['path'], PATHINFO_DIRNAME );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple way to achieve

```
str_replace(basename($articleimage), '', $articleimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the one-liners:

```
$url = implode('/', array_splice( explode('/', $articleimage), 0, -1 ) );
```

Answer (score -2):

`$url['']` and enter the appropriate number